# Set method is not called in struts2 for file input but called for other perameters

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

I am new to struts2. What I am trying is to get data from the client and insert into the db.But while doing this setImageFile(File fie) isnt called and thus imageFile object is null. While other set methods are called and is thus respective members contains values.

action.class

```java
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;
    import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
    import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
    public class register extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
        SessionMap<String, String> sessionMap;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String dob;
        private String address;
        private File imageFile;
        private String imageFileFileName;
        private String imageFileContentType;

        @Override
        public void setSession(Map map)
        {
         sessionMap = (SessionMap)map;
         sessionMap.put("", name);
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getDob() {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob(String dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public File getImageFile() {
            return imageFile;
        }


      public void setFile(File imageFile) {
            this.imageFile = imageFile;
       }
     public void setSessionMap(SessionMap<String, String> sessionMap) {
        this.sessionMap = sessionMap;
    }








      public String execute()
       {
           try
           {
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

           Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DemoDB", "postgres", "postgres");
           InputStream imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
           String query = "insert into userProfile('Name','Address','email','dob','img') values(?,?,?,?,?)";
           Date date = Date.valueOf(dob); 
           PreparedStatement preparedStatement =   conn.prepareStatement(query);
           preparedStatement.setString(0, name);
           preparedStatement.setString(1, address);
           preparedStatement.setString(2, email);
           preparedStatement.setDate(3, date);
           preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(4, imageInputStream, imageFile.length());
           preparedStatement.execute();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
           return "success";
       }
    }
```

In the above code imageFile is null. And othe members contains value

struts.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts   
    Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
    <struts>
        <package name="register" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default">
            <action name="register" class="com.passportseva.register">

                <result name="success" type="tiles">login</result>
                <result name="input" type="tiles">register</result>
                <result name="error">layoutmanager.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

This is jsp where the action is called

registration.jsp

```html
        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="register" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <div><h1>Name</h1></div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" hint="name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div><h1>Email</h1>></div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" hint="email"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div><h1>DOB</h1></div>
                    <input type="date" name="dob"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div><h1>Address</h1></div>
                    <input type="area" name="address" hint="address"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <s:file name="imageFile" label="image"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="register"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I used tiles here
tiles.xml

```xml
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC   
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"  
     "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd"> 
     <tiles-definitions>
         <definition name="login" template="/layoutmanager.jsp">
             <put-attribute name="title" value="Login Page"/>
             <put-attribute name="body" value="/login.jsp"/>
         </definition>
          <definition name="register" template="/layoutmanager.jsp">
             <put-attribute name="title" value="Passport seva registration"/>
             <put-attribute name="body" value="/registration.jsp"/>
         </definition>
     </tiles-definitions>
```

The output says that invalid field value for imageFile.

Comment: Does it work if you include the other setters (content type and file name)? Please include the *exact* error output, and include what version of S2 you're using. Unrelated, but I'd move the business logic out of the action.

Comment: Mostly you should understand the file uploading mechanism to be aware that all parts of the application work together. To get know how it works you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625712/573032) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Struts Form tag with **enctype** attribute.

```
<s:form action="register" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</s:form>
```

Comment: Good catch; didn't even look for that.